# remove index.php with alternative routing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a project in Codeigniter that doesn't use the standard routing.php file.
It calls the functions like this: test.vi/index.php/controller/function.

My goal is to remove the index.php from the url with a htaccess rewrite:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And also this config.php change:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

My question is do I need to route all the controllers/functions in my route.php or can it be done without using the route.php file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first make sure you enabled mod_rewrite in httpd.conf:

to do so add/make sure it exsits this line

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

then create .htaccess in your codeigniter root folder (next to index.php file) not application folder.

.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

codeigniter take care of all routings for you; so for

`controlers/welcome.php method=hello` u can access it by

`http://localhost/welcome/hello`

its not like laravel you need to specifically add route; codeigniter automatically Fitch controller for you. unless you have it stored in a different location or inside subfolder then you dont need to touch route.php except for setting your default route.

Comment: I tried your .htaccess still getting a 404 if I don't add index.php to the url.

Comment: did you enable rewrites in you server ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my redirect in .htaccess for a live codeigniter site.  The second part exempts certain directories.

```
#Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1     !^(index\.php|phpinfo\.php|test\.php|example\.php|images|i|css|js|beta|captcha|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS works perfect for me... give it a try..

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: using `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)` allow you to skip redirection for files/folders u specify; also avoid blocking search engines

Comment: Tried it same as the .htaccess below still 404. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.v/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I guess everyone forget about add test.vi folder name on .htaccess